# Vue.js 2.0 Blank in Edge because of <template> inline in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vuejs2

I have styled my whole single html page with template tags directly in my HTML, which acts like switches that hide and display info depending on my App data.

example:

```
<!Doctype>
<head></head>
<body>
   <template v-if="2 + 2 == 4">
   // Show code if true
   </template>
</body
```

It works in every browser except the microsoft browsers. 
Is there an easy workaround without having to rewrite every single template tag?
Im using Gulp but not browserfy. As far as i know, vuefy only precompiles template tags within a .vue file

Comment: Yes template is not supported on IE11: http://caniuse.com/#feat=template This feature is not related to vuejs by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Alright. @Cobaltway answer pointed me in the right direction. I found a polyfill which worked for IE.

For both IE and Edge however the overall problem was if statements in multiline

```
<template v-if="1+1 == 2
|| 
2+2 == 4
||
3+3 == 6
">
```

Which instead should be

```
<template v-if="1+1==2 || 2+2==4 || 3+3 == 6">
```